# How to Add Response and Request Body To Mail in JMeter?

Tags: automation, jmeter, smtp

I set SMTP Sampler for my JMeter automation. But I want to add request and response body to mail that'll send. Could you help me with that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) plugin in order to write the request and response data into a file.

[image]

Once you write the data into the file you can attach the file to your email message using "Attach file(s)" input field of the [SMTP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler):

[image]

Flexible File Writer doesn't come with JMeter bundle, you will need to install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: it is not help me. Do you know different solutions about this problem ?